# Matlab lego nxt robot doesn’t turn but says it did

Tags: matlab, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I am programming a Lego brick NXT in Matlab to go through a maze. The robot is supposed to drive forward until the touch sensor is activated by a wall.

The robot should

1. stop
2. backup
3. stop
4. read the ultraSonic (distance) sensor
5. display the result

If the sensor reads a large distance, the robot turns right and stops and if the sensor reads a small distance, the robot turns left and stops.

Then, the robot continues forward again until it runs into another wall.

Current code:

The robot will hit the wall, stop, back up, stop, and it will display that it’s turning, but it doesn’t turn.

Is there something I am typing incorrectly? Should I initialize the motors before the loop or inside of the loop? I am especially wary of my pauses.

```
  1 %B = NXTMotor('B');
  2 %C = NXTMotor('C');
  3 OpenSwitch(SENSOR_1);
  4 OpenUltrasonic(SENSOR_4);
  5 
  6 
  7 while 1
  8 
  9     B = NXTMotor('B');
 10     C = NXTMotor('C');
 11 
 12     %FORWARD 1 
 13     disp('move forward');
 14     B.Power = 50;
 15     C.Power = 50;
 16  
 17     B.SendToNXT();
 18     C.SendToNXT(); 
 19     B.WaitFor();
 20     C.WaitFor();
 21     disp('before getswitch');
 22 
 23         if GetSwitch(SENSOR_1)
 24             pause(0.2);
 25             B.Power = 0;
 26             C.Power = 0;
 27             B.SendToNXT();
 28             C.SendToNXT();
 29             B.WaitFor();
 30             C.WaitFor();
 31             disp('Hit a wall and stops'); 
 32             
 33             disp('back up');
 34             B.Power = -50;
 35             C.Power = -50;
 36             
 37             B.TachoLimit = 720;
 38             C.TachoLimit = 720;
 39  
 40             B.SendToNXT();
 41             C.SendToNXT();
 42             B.WaitFor();
 43             C.WaitFor();
 44             
 45             pause(0.5);
 46             B.Power = 0;
 47             C.Power = 0;
 48             B.SendToNXT();
 49             C.SendToNXT();
 50             B.WaitFor();
 51             C.WaitFor();
 52             disp('finished back up');
 53             
 54             %ultrasonic
 55             distance = GetUltrasonic(SENSOR_4);
 56             disp(distance);
 57             
 58             if distance >100
 59             %if GetUltrasonic(SENSOR_4) > 100
 60 
 61                 %TURN 1
 62                 disp('turn1 > 100');
 63                      
 64                 B.Power = 0;
 65                 C.Power = 100;
 66  
 67                 B.TachoLimit = 720;
 68                 C.TachoLimit = 720;
 69  
 70                 B.SendToNXT();
 71                 C.SendToNXT();
 72                 B.WaitFor();
 73                 C.WaitFor();
 74                 disp('turn1 finished');
 75             
 76                 pause(0.2);
 77                 B.Power = 0;
 78                 C.Power = 0;
 79                 B.SendToNXT();
 80                 C.SendToNXT();
 81                 B.WaitFor();
 82                 C.WaitFor();
 83             
 84             end
 85             
 86             if distance <= 100
 87           
 88                 disp('turn2 < 100');
 89             
 90                 B.Power = 100;
 91                 C.Power = 0;
 92                 disp('turn 2'); 
 93                 B.TachoLimit = 720;
 94                 C.TachoLimit = 720;
 95  
 96                 B.SendToNXT();
 97                 C.SendToNXT();
 98                 B.WaitFor();
 99                 C.WaitFor();
100                 disp('Finished turn 2'); 
101             
102                 pause(0.5);
103                 B.Power = 0;
104                 C.Power = 0;
105                 B.SendToNXT();
106                 C.SendToNXT();
107                 B.WaitFor();
108                 C.WaitFor();
109             
110                 disp('stopped turn2 and ready to go forward');
111           
112             end
113             
114             B.Stop('off');
115             C.Stop('off');
116         end
117     
118         %B.Stop('off');
119         %C.Stop('off');
120     end
121 
122     CloseSensor(SENSOR_4);
123     CloseSensor(SENSOR_1);
```

Comment: Possible better questioned at http://bricks.stackexchange.com/ - but please read their [guidelines](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. I'm not that sure about it.

Comment: They only had three results when I pulled up matlab. I can post there and give it a shot, though.

Comment: Here is only one result (your post) with tags matlab and lego. ;)

Comment: I could be wrong - but this might help: Why is `if statement` at line 23 ending at line 116? Shouldn't this be done at e.g. line 53 or similar? And if you're using `if distance > 100` and `if distance <= 100` you can also use `if distance > 100` … __`else`__. Or am I wrong?

Comment: and again: There is also a missing `end` at the end of the code for `while 1` in line 7